# How to layout a grid like Facebook's Album Post

Tags: html, css

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of grid in facebook's album post?
I tried to Inspect Element it and all I see is that

```
<div class="image-grid">
    <a href="#">
        <div> <img src="image1.jpg"> </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div> <img src="image1.jpg"> </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div> <img src="image1.jpg"> </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div> <img src="image1.jpg"> </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see the CSS of the respective element in style tab of inspect elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook like image gallery with count of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221269/facebook-like-image-gallery-with-count-of-images)